# Why my project bundle after AOT is larger in size than my previous JIT bundle?

Tags: angular, typescript, jit, angular2-aot

Previously I was making my **production build** for my angular project by following below steps:

1. tsc (compilation with es2015)
2. rollup es5 (recompiling the bundle.2015.js to bundle.js)
3. minify (minifying and uglifying)
4. Gzip

After all the above steps the bundle size is **250 KB.**

But now I have implementing **AOT** instead of JIT and after all the steps the size is **470KB** approx. I'm not understanding that is this a problem, does after AOT compilation size increases ? is this usually happen ? if not then what am I doing wrong.

Regards

Comment: I'm guessing you are using Angular 2.x? I believe that's normal. Lot of work has been done since and in Angular 4.x AoT size is improved considerably. If you are using 4.x, then ignore this (;

Comment: Yes, it's expected. The generated JavaScript code is larger than the original HTML code (although angular 4 has improved this). On the other hand, the angular compiler should not be part of your bundle (or vendor bundle) anymore, which reduces the size. The end result depends on the size of your application. For small apps, the removal of the compiler more than compensates the increase caused by the AOT compilation. For large apps with many templates, it doesn't anymore.